# In pure XAML, is it possible to get a Line to align to part of a Grid?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, line

Is it possible to create a Line in XAML (without any C# code behind) to align a line inside of a layout container such as a Grid?

I'd like to effectively have:

```
<Grid>
    <Line StrokeThickness="1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
          Stroke="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

I need to use `StrokeDashArray` and `StrokeDashOffset`, otherwise I would just use a `Border` control with the BorderThickness set to `"0,0,0,1"`...

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To elaborate on kanchirk's response, this works for me:

```
<Path StrokeThickness="1"
 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
 Data="M0,0 L1,0"
 Stretch="Fill"
 StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
 StrokeStartLineCap="Square"
 Stroke="Red"/>
```

You can also the same thing with a `Line`:

```
<Line StrokeThickness="1" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
 VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
 X2="1" 
 Stretch="Fill" 
 StrokeEndLineCap="Square" 
 StrokeStartLineCap="Square" 
 Stroke="Red"/>
```

Comment: Thanks - it's pretty good, and does answer my question as phrased. Marking as answered.


However, I really want to use this to mimic fancy underlining for a text block, so I don't want it to stretch larger than it needs to to fill the container.

Comment: Are you saying it will become wider than its container? Perhaps you should create a more specific question (and link to it from here) if this won't actually work for you.

Comment: @Gabe The problem is that `Stretch=Fill` makes it harder if not impossible to use `StrokeDashArray` and related properties to create a dotted/dashed line, since it will "stretch" instead of "tile" the dots/dashes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use **Path** like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

<Path Fill="Red" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1" Height="4" Margin="8,0,7,7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" UseLayoutRounding="False" Data="M8,127 L457,127" StrokeThickness="13"/>

</Grid>
```

Hope this Helps. Expression Blend is a must have for this kind of Challenges or even VS 2010 RC1 (For now)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<Line x:Name="line" 
StrokeThickness="1"  
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  
Stroke="Red" 
X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=line, Mode=OneWay}"
Stretch="Fill" 
StrokeStartLineCap="Square"
StrokeEndLineCap="Square"/>
```

Comment: Binding is interesting, thanks. For performance reasons though I'm weary to use it.

Comment: @gabe, you right. I missed Stretch, StrokeStartLineCap and StrokeEndLineCap. Now it'll be fine. Anyway, Your solution is better for all. :D

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only answer that actually satisfies the original question's requirement of being able to use `StrokeDashArray` and related properties to create a dotted/dashed line. Just one issue: binding directly to `ActualWidth` may not work as expected since it does not notify on update in Silverlight and WinRT. However there are ways to work around that as detailed in the [answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602148/binding-to-actualwidth-does-not-work). Also, `Strech="Fill"` is unnecessary and can be removed.