# Why ActualSize is not updating its value on WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I have the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="UnderstandSizing.Window2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="Column1" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Column1,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I expected to see at the textbox the value of the width of the column Column1 but all I can see is 0.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602148/binding-to-actualwidth-does-not-work) and [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/425334/binding-to-actualwidth-ignores-changes-in-silverlight) but everywhere says that is related only to Silverlight, not WPF.

**Edit**
Fixed a typo. Also to note that the Output window do not show any binding issue . What is strange to me is that it is working in the designer. It stops working only on runtime.

Comment: You have a typo. "ElementName=Colum1" should be "ElementName=Column1"

Comment: @theartwebreathe: nope, the typo was entered while putting the code at SO :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't this be a circular reference? The width of "Column1" is dependent on the `Text` of your `TextBox`, and the `Text` of your `TextBox` is dependent on the width of "Column1". I don't see how WPF could ever possibly resolve a value for this unless you explicitly set the width of either "Column1" or your `TextBox`.

**Edit**

Oh, I see the problem. `ActualWidth` is a `double` not a dependency property, so you will never receive an update when the value gets calculated.

You need to use @Robert Levy's suggestion of putting a dummy control in the space occupied by your `TextBox` and bind to the `ActualWidth` of that instead.

Comment: If that was the case I would expect a never ending loop not a 0. Anyway the text 100 needs the same space as 110.

Comment: The zero may be WPF's way of dealing with the infinite loop.

Comment: I've tried changing to the rowheight and the same happens, so looks like this is not what is happening because the row has the same height with or without text.

Comment: Try this: change the width of your two column definitions to `*` instead of `Auto`. If the binding is working, your `TextBlock` should show "150".

Comment: None. No errors, no warnings. The binding working in designtime and not in runtime.

Comment: Sorry but the MSDN says that is a DP. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx

Comment: @Robert, good question. I have asked myself the same thing with several properties throughout WPF. AFAIK, just about every property of every control should be a DP, but I guess the WPF team felt differently when it designed the classes.

Comment: @SoMoS, `ColumnnDefinition` is not a `FrameworkElement`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.aspx. It's actually a `FrameworkContentElement`, which is not the same thing. Here is the page for the actual property -- it clearly says `double` for `ActualWidth`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.actualwidth.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Interesting...

As DanM found, ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth is not a dependency property so you wont get binding updates when it changes.

A workaround is to put a hidden control in the column and bind to it's ActualWidth like this:

```
    <ContentControl Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="hidden"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=hidden,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Weird, but its something to start with ... so the broken thing is the Grid column?

Comment: Right. It's working but I would prefer another solution if possible, if not I will mark your response as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in this line of XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Colum1,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

`ElementName` should be Column1 instead of Colum1.

One of the nice things about XAML is that it will still run if you have done an improper binding, and one of the frustrating things about XAML is that it will still run if you have done an improper binding.

**EDIT**

If you bind to the ActualWidth of the textbox itself, that is within the column, it will work just fine.

```
<TextBox Name="tbk1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=tbk1, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

or, more simply (no requirement to name the textbox):

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: Nope, the typo was entering the code at SO :( Can you try the code on your machine?

Comment: Code runs perfectly on my machine with the typo fixed.  Shows the actual column width, even at design time.

Comment: Only at design time, try at runtime, please. I have two machines, one with 2008 and another one with 2010 and both reproduce the issue ¿?

Comment: Looks a good solution, similar to what Robert said. How do you know its a circular reference?