# Binding the height of a border to its width

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

I've got a strange issue with the layout of my Windows Phone App.
I have a grid, with 4 columns. Inside each, I put a Border, and i would like these borders to be perfect square (even if my container height changes...).

Here is the relevant code :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"  Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"><TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" /></Border>
<Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"><TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" /></Border>
<Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Red" Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"><TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" /></Border>
<Border Grid.Column="3" Background="Red" Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"><TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" /></Border>

</Grid>
```

It renders great in Blend:

[image]

But when I run it on the simulator, my borders are gone (looks like the height got to 0).

I don't have any Code on codebehind..

Do anybody have any thoughts on my issue ?

Thanxs,

Comment: Do you observe any binding error messages in Visual Studio's output window?

Comment: No, nothing in the output about my bindings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying bind to the ActualWidth/ActualHeight property. From an older question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602148/binding-to-actualwidth-does-not-work)), this is a known issue with Silverlight, and there is no simple workaround.

Try something else such as bind to Width & specify a column width :

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"  Width="100" Height="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Red"  Width="100" Height="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Red"  Width="100" Height="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" Background="Red"  Width="100" Height="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: In fact I will just use SizeChanged event, because hardcoding a width is not ideal. Thanxs for the light of the "bug" with binding ActualWidth!