# Silverlight Runtime Binding to Custom Dependency Object

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

I've searched everywhere so if I'm making a double posting please forgive me.

I need a binding for the ActualHeight Property of a Border Control.  I've used this post to get started:
[Binding to ActualWidth does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602148/binding-to-actualwidth-does-not-work)

which in turn took me to this blog:
http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/07/binding-actualheight-and-actualwidth.html

where I've implemented a Class for the SizeChange and all looks good in the land of code.

My control is being created at Runtime, so I create the control, and add a Property for "IsEnabled" as per the XAML Based code

```
border.SetValue( SizeChange.IsEnabledProperty, true );
```

I've checked it by debugging the code and it's updating the SizeChange.ActualHeight correctly.  Next I'm trying to bind another runtime created control to this one:

```
Binding weekHeight = new Binding( "SizeChange.ActualHeight" );
weekHeight.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
weekHeight.Source = border;
border2.SetBinding( Border.HeightProperty, weekHeight );
```

Now the XAML Based solution calls for a Binding of "local_ui:SizeChange.ActualHeight" but that causes a runtime error if I try that, and instead I've used "SizeChange.ActualHeight" which passes but it's not updating the size of my control.

I've tried to keep things straight forward so please forgive me if I missed something.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you need an actual height? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Nifty technique, btw - nice find!

Comment: The border control ActualHeight doesn't update, Silverlight bug, so the work around is needed to get it as another control needs to set it's height to the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question is (in essence) how to bind a custom attached property from code-behind.  The trick is to set the binding path using `PropertyPath`, instead of a string.  Construct it using the actual dependency property (SizeChange.ActualHeightProperty), like this:

```
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(SizeChange.ActualHeightProperty);
```

So the binding constructor should look like this:

```
Binding weekHeight = new Binding 
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(SizeChange.ActualHeightProperty),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
    Source = border
};
border2.SetBinding( Border.HeightProperty, weekHeight );
```

Comment: Oh... My... Goodness... Is it difficult being so bloody clever?!  I was so close and yet so far... Thank you so much, I really don't know how you guys just suck this stuff out of thin air.  Really appreciate the assist!